# Removing device from USB hub triggers udev event for removing hub

Tags: usb, udev

I have a udev rule to halt the system when a usb hub is removed:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ACTION=="remove", ENV{ID_VENDOR_ID}="050d", ENV{ID_MODEL_ID}="0237", RUN+="/sbin/halt"
```

Unfortunately, this also triggers when a device plugged into that hub is removed.  I have looked through output from `udevadm monitor --udev --property` while plugging and unplugging the devices and there is no set of fields which can be isolated as unique to removing the hub.

Does anyone know how I can target just the hub and not include remove events for devices attached to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guess who used "=" instead of "==", meaning the rule would match any remove event?  Whoops...

There is a lot of overlap in the two sets of events but the line that will target that hub is:

```
ACTION=="remove", ENV{PRODUCT}=="50d/237/100", RUN+="/sbin/shutdown -h now"
```